# Chain rule for a functional derivative.

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, calculus-of-variations, frechet-derivative, gateaux-derivative

Given $L:\mathbb{R}\times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of probability densities on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to calculate

$$ \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon \to 0}L(\rho(x)+\alpha(x),\rho+\epsilon \alpha ), $$
where $\alpha=\tilde{\rho}-\rho$, and $\tilde{\rho},\rho\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Is my calculation correct : $$ \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon \to 0}L(\rho(x)+\epsilon\alpha(x),\rho+\epsilon \alpha )=\alpha(x) L'(\rho(x),\rho)+dL(\rho(x),\rho;\alpha)$$
with $dL(\rho(x),\rho;\alpha)$ the Gateaux derivative?

Comment: The answer depends on what $L$ is. You did not write what is $L'$ and $dL$. The $dL(...)$ term should not be there -  guess. Also why does the first argument reduce from $\rho+\alpha$ to $\rho$?

Comment: @daw there was a typo there should of been epsilon in the first term so it should of reduced. $L'(\rho(x),\rho)$ is the derivative of the function $L(\cdot,\rho):\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ (where the second argument is kept constant).

Comment: I believe that this definition of functional derivative is invalid in this space since it isn't a vector space. You can't add probability distributions and get another probability distribution back in general

Comment: @whpowell96 $\alpha$ is the difference of two probability density so that $\rho+\alpha$ is a probability density

Comment: But surely $p + \epsilon \alpha$ can't be one for any $\epsilon$ can it? One can view probability densities as lying in elements of larger function spaces that are vector spaces, which would allow you to compute this derivative with respect to the topology of the larger space, but I don't think you can do this with respect to the topology of the space of probability distributions, which is just a metric space, not a vectoer space. I believe a lot of the theory of gradient flows in metric spaces was introduced to deal with the fact that traditional derivatives aren't defined no metric spaces.

Comment: @whpowell96 it integrates to 1 and is non-negative (for $\epsilon \in[0,1])$ since pointwise $\tilde{\rho}$ is non-negative and so is $(1-\epsilon)\rho$. But yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your original (now deleted) post, I will assume that you're trying to compute the first variation of a functional $\mathscr F$ over the space of probability measures, as defined in chapter 7 of Santambrogio's [Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematicians](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-20828-2).

First thing to note is that in that case, $\mathscr F$ is actually defined for **absolutely continous** measures by the expression
$$\mathscr F(\mu) := \int_{\mathbb R^n} L(\rho(x),\rho)\ d\lambda(x) $$
Where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\rho:=\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda} $ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\lambda$. Hence for the above expression to make sense, we need $L$ to be defined on $X := \mathbb R\times L^1(\mathbb R^n) $, where $L^1(\mathbb R^n) $ is the space of measurable and integrable functions on $\mathbb R^n$ (that is because any probability density is automatically integrable by definition). Also I took the domain to be $\mathbb R^n$ to fix ideas, but you can clearly replace it by any suitable $\Omega$ you wish.

Now to compute the first variation of $\mathscr F$, you can let $\theta$ be any density function on $\mathbb R^n $ (or any $L^1$ function really) and let $\chi := \theta\cdot\lambda $, so that for any $\varepsilon >0$

$$\mathscr F(\mu +\varepsilon \chi) - \mathscr F(\mu) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \big[L(\rho(x) + \varepsilon\theta(x), \rho + \varepsilon\theta) - L(\rho(x),\rho)\big]\ d\lambda(x) $$

Hence we can see that under suitable regularity conditions, the first variation of $\mathscr F$ in direction $\chi$ will be given by
$$\frac{\delta \mathscr F}{\delta \mu}(\mu) : x\in\mathbb R^n\mapsto dL(\rho(x),\rho;\tilde\theta(x)) $$
Where $\tilde \theta(x) := (\theta(x),\theta)\in X$ and $dL(\rho(x),\rho;\tilde \theta(x))$ denotes the Gâteaux derivative of $L$ at $(\rho(x),x)\in X$ in direction $\tilde \theta(x)$.